# Can a surface of the following type contain a line?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

This is a follow-up question to my previous post: [Sufficient conditions to tell whether a surface contains a line](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81722/sufficient-conditions-to-tell-whether-a-surface-contains-a-line)

Suppose that $f(x_1, x_2)$ is an irreducible binary form with integer coefficients of the variables $x_1, x_2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ say, and suppose that $g(x_1, x_2)$ is another binary form with integer coefficients (not necessarily the same degree as $f$) that does not have a common component as $f$. In the case I am interested in this condition is satisfied vacuously since we assume $\deg(g) < \deg(f)$. Now, can the surface
$$f(x_1, x_2) = g(x_3, x_4)$$
(in weighted projective space) contain any lines?

Note: the case $f = g = x^d + y^d$ has been treated by Heath-Brown, I believe.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, one cannot view what you have written down ($f(x_1,x_2)=g(x_3,x_4)$) as a being a surface unless $f$ and $g$ are homogeneous of the same degree, and also in which case you need to consider the corresponding variety as being projective.

Comment: You can consider it as a surface in a weighted projective space $\mathbb{P}(a,a,b,b)$ such that $a\text{deg}(f)$ equals $b\text{deg}(g)$ (and probably best to assume that $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime).  

Comment: Yes; I do mean a surface in weighted projective space.

Comment: But in weighted projective space what do you mean by a line? Just a rational curve?

Comment: Would the existence of a rational curve in a surface imply the existence of many rational solutions?